# Finding which functions are bounded by $O(n^2)$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

I am asked to select the functions that are bounded by the Big-Oh function O(n^2): $f(n) \in O(n^2)$.

1. $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} n$
2. $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i$
3. $f(n) = n + n^2$
4. $f(n) = 1$

I choose the answers 1, 2, and 4:

1. Simplifies to $n \cdot n = n^2$, which is **bounded** by $O(n^2)$
2. Simplifies to $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} = n^2/2 + 1/2$, which is **bounded** by $O(n^2)$
3. $n^2 + n$ is obviously not bounded by $O(n^2)$
4. $1$ is obviously **bounded** by $O(n^2)$

However, it was alerted to me that one of my answers is incorrect. That seems strange, considering that after expanding all the expressions mathematically, I believe that I have chosen whether they are bounded by $n^2$ correctly.

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of big O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $n^2 + n = O(n^2)$. Indeed, if $n \geq 1$ then $n^2 \geq n$ and so
$$
n^2 + n \leq 2n^2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

I know, that answer is done, is correct and is accepted, but let me add, that "function is bounded by $O(n^2)$" is not completely correct sentence and as such can lead to errors:  $O(n^2)$ is set, so we can speak about boundedness by some member from it, but exact is to say, that **function is bounded by some** $\boldsymbol n^{ \boldsymbol 2}$ **factor**, starting from some number up to infinity.